# Outlook 2010 Redemption RDOSelectNamesDialog "Attempted to read or write protected memory" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-redemption

I am trying to display the SelectNamesDialog in Outlook 2010, using Redemption in C#, but I am getting the exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." on the third line below:

```
RDOSession rdoSess = new RDOSession();
rdoSess.MAPIOBJECT = Reflection.GetProperty(Application.Session, "MAPIObject");
RDOSelectNamesDialog dlg = rdoSess.GetSelectNamesDialog();
```

My Outlook application object is valid (the standard SelectNamesDialog works ok) and I am using reflection to get the MAPIObject property from the session as it does not appear in the intellisense.

I have downloaded the latest version of Redemption and have referenced the Interop.Redemption file. I am running Windows 7 32-bit and Visual Studio 2010, using the .NET 4 Framework.

Has anyone else seen this error before? I suspect I am doing something wrong, but my code seems to match the Redemption samples I have found online.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance,

Nathan.

Comment: What is the value of the rdoSess.Version property?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, rdoSess.Version = "5.0.0.2174"

Comment: RDOSession.GetSelectNames dialog was added in version 5.1. Are you sure you installed the latest version of Redemption?

Comment: You are absolutely right! It looks like I had an older version registered elsewhere on the PC, so it wasn't using the DLL I thought it was! I've registered the new one and the dialog now displays. Thank you so much for your help! Can't believe it was such a simple solution. Thanks again, Nathan.

Comment: Every time you get an access violation error in .Net, it pretty much means .Net tried to invoke a method past the v-table. That can only happen if you are calling a method that was not present in the older versions.